# AS3 - End of file was encountered

Tags: actionscript-3

By trying to create a bitmap out of a ByteArray I received this error:

> ERROR #2030: End of file was encountered.

This is my ActionScript:

```
var myBitmapData_2:BitmapData = new BitmapData (50, 50, false, 0xFFFFFF);
        var rect_2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
        myBitmapData_2.setPixels(rect_2, savedImage[0]);
        var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData_2);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is `savedImage[0]`?

Comment: An image as a bytearray.

Comment: I mean where do you get it? Did you try `ByteArray(savedImage[0]).position = 0;` before `setPixels` function?

Comment: Ok that solved the error but the image is just a bunch of grainy random colors. Do I need to uncompress the bytearray before the setPixels or something?

Comment: So again, how do you get this ByteArray?

Comment: It's generated by a JPEGEncoder.

Comment: Well, `setPixels` method receives only `A ByteArray object that consists of 32-bit unmultiplied pixel values to be used in the rectangular region`, and ByteArray from JPEGEncoder is totally not the same thing. I don't know what is your main goal of doing that, but if it's important to do exactly like that, you have to decode your ByteArray. Maybe [this](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1089) will help.

Comment: seems like [`Loader.loadBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes()) would be easier.